# Getting Html From calling jQuery custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a custom function and am trying to call it in a separate function and get the elements html. What am I missing?

Custom Function: (wizard.js)

```
function wizard() {

    var wizardBody = $(this).html();

    console.log(wizardBody);

}

jQuery.fn.wizard = wizard;
```

Calling Said function on element: (config.js)

```
// Initiate Web Design Get Started Wizard 
$("#webDesignGetStartedWizard").wizard();
```

I simply get `undefined` with the current code above, if I don't call the function on the html ($(this).html) then I get the following:

```
ƒ (e){return z(this,function(e){var t=this[0]||{},n=0,r=this.length;if(void 0===e&&1===t.nodeType)return t.innerHTML;if("string"==typeof e&&!Ae.test(e)&&!ge[(de.exec(e)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()]){e=w…
```

**UPDATE**

So the problem seems to be related to the use of my router plugin, `jq-router` Because if I take `#webDesignGetStartedWizard` out of the template and place it in my index file, it works perfectly.

```
https://github.com/muzammilkm/jq-router
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work correctly make sure `config.js` and `wizard.js` loaded in the document correctly. You should load the `wizard.js` and then include `config.js` and also make sure the `div#webDesignGetStartedWizard` available when the script is called.

See a demo of your code.

```js
function wizard() {

  var wizardBody = $(this).html();

  console.log(wizardBody);

}

jQuery.fn.wizard = wizard;

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Initiate Web Design Get Started Wizard 
  $("#webDesignGetStartedWizard").wizard();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="webDesignGetStartedWizard">
  <p>current text in the paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, okay! I see something now. I'm using a router plugin and that's what is preventing it from working. I'll update my question.